# name echo twice in user online list

Tags: php, mysql

I have an area on my site where I'd like for all current users online to be able to see all other users current online. If you are a logged in user you should see your own user name as well.

The code below accomplishes the task except for the fact that the current user sees his name twice. I've already twisted my brain looking at this piece of code and I can appreciate a fresh perspective, can anyone see the issue?

```
<?php
$select_query = @mysql_query(
    "select * from player_log where log_status='online'"
);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($select_query)) {
    extract($row);
    $select_query_p = @mysql_query("select * from players_signup where id=$id");
    $name = mysql_result($select_query_p, 0, 'name');
    ?>
    <div class="users"><?php echo $name; ?></div>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Before you try to fix this code, I would highly recommend you to change to [`mysqli_*`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and then I will welcome you in 2015!

Comment: Oh Leon, thats such a mess. Dont use the mysql_ extension. Dont use `extract()` like that use the field names you actually want like `$row['id']`. Also dont us `@` to stop error mesages, instead fix the errors!

Comment: @Rizier123 I rather liked the *Retro 80's* myself!

Comment: lol, you guys turned this into a roast. Anyway, this piece of code is from someone i had Previously contracted to do some development work, since then i have let him go and decided to learn php on my own. Im trying to clean up his mess, my code utilizes mysqli. Although the comments are someone helpful, the things you guys are pointing out is not the solution to my problem

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your `$id` doesn't really change when execute `mysql_query("select * from players_signup where id=$id")` each time in the while-loop.

Try:

```
$id = $row['id'];
$select_query_p=@mysql_query("select * from players_signup where id=$id");
```